# How to select drop-down value after POST in ColdFusion script using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have written simple form with an `onload` function which always pre-populates market values. But when I select one market value from the drop-down list and after submitting the form the value should stay selected in the drop-down. Here's the related code:

```
<html>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <cfif isdefined("form.submit")>
    form submitted
    <cfdump var="#form#">
  </cfif>

  <body onload="myFunction()">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <cfform action="dropdowntest.cfm" method="post">
      <cfselect name="market1" id="market1"></cfselect>
      <br> <br>
      <button id="addTypes1" >add types</button><br> <br>
      <CFINPUT class="but" TYPE="submit" NAME="SUBMIT" VALUE="SEARCH">
    </cfform>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      //var selectedVal = $("#market1").val();
      var kinds = ["A", "B", "C"];
      $.each(kinds, function(index, value) {         
        $("#market1").append("<option value='"+value+"'>" +value+ "</option>");
        //$("#market1").val('selectedVal')
      });
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to select the value again after POST?

Comment: if you submit the page will refresh and it will reset the select. unless you want to save the value in local storage and load it when page loads

Comment: You need to save those values somewhere at the time of submitting the form. Once submitted, page reloads and any unsaved data is gone. You should save it on server and get it back on page load.

Comment: The form scope is available to you when you post the form.  Use it.

Answer (score 0):

The drop-down list will lose its value, because you are posting the form. So you need to retain it and set it on load. One way to do this is to use a [cookie](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie).

```
$('select[name=market1]').on('change', function() {
  $.cookie("marketVal", this.value );
});
```

Now within the `onload` function you can check whether this cookie value is present and set the selected market value from it.

```
function myFunction() {
  var selectedVal = $.cookie("marketVal" );
  var kinds = ["A", "B", "C"];
  $.each(kinds, function(index, value) {         
    $("#market1").append("<option value='"+value+"'>" +value+ "</option>");
  });
  if(selectedVal) {
    $("#market1").val(selectedVal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a cookie?  You already have the form scope at it's disposal.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing the options via jQuery you could write them directly in ColdFusion:

```cf
<cfselect name="market1" id="market1">
  <cfloop array="#['A', 'B', 'C']#" item="val">
    <option value="#val#"
        #structKeyExists(FORM, "market1") and FORM.market1 eq val ?
        " selected" : ""#>#val#</option>
  </cfloop>
</cfselect>
```

Only when you load the data asynchronously you need to fill the drop-down list in jQuery, which may look like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var kinds = ["A", "B", "C"];
  $.each(kinds, function(index, value){
    $("##market1").append("<option value='"+value+"'>" +value+ "</option>");
  });
  <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "market1")>
    $("##market1 > option[value=#FORM.market1#]").prop("selected", true);
  </cfif>
}
</script>
```